# portia No Such Resource File not found

Tags: python, portia

I am following the [README](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/tree/master) of the portia github repo and I am stuck at running th server

I followd the instructions fo running portia locally

```
twistd -n slyd
```

and when I enter the url

> http://localhost:9001/static/main.html

in the browser I get the 404 error

> **No Such Resource**
>
> File not found.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer in this [issue](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/issues/150) on github.